# For loop terminating early in nested ifs and function due to return

Tags: python, function, for-loop, if-statement, return

I am trying to solve the following practice question:

"Imagine you're writing the software for an inventory system for
a store. Part of the software needs to check to see if inputted
product codes are valid.

A product code is valid if all of the following conditions are
true:

- The length of the product code is a multiple of 4. It could
  be 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, etc. characters long.
- Every character in the product code is either an uppercase
  character or a numeral. No lowercase letters or punctuation
  marks are permitted.
- The character sequence "A1" appears somewhere in the
  product code.

Write a function called valid_product_code. valid_product_code
should have one parameter, a string. It should return True if
the string is a valid product code, and False if it is not."

```
def valid_product_code(code):
    if len(code)%4 == 0:
        if "A1" in code:
            if code.isalnum():
                for character in code:
                    #print(character) 
                    #print statement above when uncommented used to 
                    #check if the loop is actually running as intended
                    if character.isupper() or character.isdigit():
                        return True
                    else:
                        return False
            else:
                return False
        else:
            return False
    else:
        return False
```

The practice question had several test strings, of which they included the following:

```
print(valid_product_code("A12B44BP"))
print(valid_product_code("BFDSAUSA98932RWEFOEWA9FEAA1DSFSF"))
print(valid_product_code("A1BBD5"))
print(valid_product_code("BDD5664S"))
print(valid_product_code("66aBSaA1fdsv"))
```

My code worked for the first four examples, resulting in `True, True, False, False` but while the last one should be `False`, I got `True`. After attempting some debugging (hence the `print(character)` in the for loop and changing the `return True` and `return False` to `print(True)` and `print(False)` statements respectively), the `print` statements I used to check indicated that lowercase letters all had `False` values whereas numbers and uppercase letters had `True` values as intended.

I had no problems with the 3 outer `if` statements, but once I needed to isolate lowercase characters I thought a for-each loop would suffice but the fact that this is a function means `return` is terminating my function prematurely and not allowing me to actually indicate that the presence of even a single lowercase letter in the whole string should render the value of the whole string as `False`. I feel something is missing, like maybe that I am putting my `return` statements in the wrong place, or have I simply approached this question the wrong way?

Please help and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your innermost loop is not implemented correctly. At the moment, `if character.isupper() or character.isdigit():` will return `True` as soon as it detects the first 6.

You need to check for each element. This can be done in the following way. I am highlighting the modified lines by a comment `#`

```
def valid_product_code(code):
    if len(code)%4 == 0:
        if "A1" in code:
            if code.isalnum():
                for character in code:
                    if not (character.isupper() or character.isdigit()): # <---
                        return False # <----
                return True # <---
            else:
                return False
        else:
            return False
    else:
        return False
```

---

```
print(valid_product_code("A12B44BP"))
print(valid_product_code("BFDSAUSA98932RWEFOEWA9FEAA1DSFSF"))
print(valid_product_code("A1BBD5"))
print(valid_product_code("BDD5664S"))
print(valid_product_code("66aBSaA1fdsv"))

True
True
False
False
False
```

---

**Alternatively**, you can combine your if statements to make the code more compact as

```
def valid_product_code(code):
    if len(code)%4 == 0 and "A1" in code and code.isalnum():
                for character in code:
                    if not (character.isupper() or character.isdigit()):
                        return False
                return True
    else:
        return False
```